# What is the ` pod_cpu_utilization_over_pod_limit` compare to ` pod_cpu_utilization`

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am deploying PODs on AWS EKS cluster and deployed a cloudwatch agent to send metrics. When I look at the metrics, I found two  `pod_cpu_utilization_over_pod_limit` and  `pod_cpu_utilization`.

My `pod_cpu_utilization` metric shows less than 50% but `pod_cpu_utilization_over_pod_limit` on the same pod shows 99%. It seems the later uses a part of the total cpu. I wonder whet the different between them .

How can I increase `pod_cpu_utilization_over_pod_limit` to use all `pod_cpu_utilization`?

Comment: My guess is that `pod_cpu_utilization_over_pod_limit` takes into account the `limit` value specified for the pod. So if you have specified a limit of 2CPU on the pod, and it's using just shy of 2CPU, then the `pod_cpu_utilization_over_pod_limit` would be near 100%. However, if that pod was running on a node with 4 CPU, then the `pod_cpu_utilization` would be just shy of 50%. This is just an educated guess, mind you.

Comment: You may checkout this documentation to understand the difference https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Container-Insights-reference-performance-entries-EKS.html